# Identity Server 4 and BlazorWA X-Frame-Options

Tags: identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.1, blazor-client-side, x-frame-options

I have a Blazor WA Application that is using Identity Server 4 Service for authenticating users. Everything works fine locally. The issue comes when I try and publish to Azure. Since the IDS is published at one address and Blazor at another, i get the X-Frame error when calling from "https://blazor..."

"Refused to display 'https://identity...' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'."

I've added

```
builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
{
     options.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;
});
```

to the Blazor startup and to the Identity start up (just for giggles) but the error remains.

Any ideas?

TYIA

Comment: Is that an iFrame for check_session endpoint? i.e. silent refresh?

Comment: No, its a redirect to the IdentityServer login page

Comment: You can't display the login page in an iframe, regardless if you're using Blazor or any other framework. Can you show us your login page code?

Comment: See Answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is to set the CORS settings in Azure to allow all (*) or the specific URL in question "https://blazor...".

I had done that at one point but for some reason it didn't work. After consulting with an Azure tech we tried it again and it worked.

¯_(ツ)_/¯